# VS 2012 linker very slow sometimes

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012, linker

We're using VS 2012 for a native C++ project. The project is cmake-based, and some of its dependencies (some libraries and headers) are on a network. The problem that we're facing is that with VS 2012, sometimes (1 out of 5 maybe), the linking process takes 10 minutes or more, while the same code-base links fine (in about 2 min) with VS 2010. Also, many times the code seems to be in an inconsistent state, since no break-points are hit, and some functions are not called at all (which should be). At these cases we usually restart VS or the machine if restarting VS fails which sometimes solves the problem.

I should mention that the project is cross-platform, and compiles fine in Linux & Mac OS X, and also, with VS 2010 without any problems (during linking). The solution takes about 18 min to compile and link in windows (under normal circumstances).

I would like to ask if there is some maintenance procedure that should be performed for VS 2012 (e.g erasing some folders) or some other action that can pinpoint or solve this problem.

**Update**: I would like to mention also, that the problem seems to be worse, when opening more than one VS 2012 instance, although I cannot prove it.

**Update 2:** The problems do not manifest, when executing the build process from the command line

**Update 3:** After following some advice from the MSDN forums, setting "Link Status" to YES (/LTCG:STATUS) which disables the incremental linker, seems to correct the problem with the inconsistent code state. Still, I do not know that is causing the incremental linker to fail though.

Thanks.

PS: VS 2012 is updated to the last available version (Update 3)

Comment: Sounds like you have 'whole program optimization' turned on in your VS2012 project (it's supported in both versions). It's worthwhile but it can take a while to perform. One thing it does is eliminate function calls i.e. inline the function.

Comment: @john how do you explain the fact that the problem appears "sometimes" and not always ?

Comment: Maybe its something related to your Netowrk..

Comment: @John I can't, except to say maybe the linker caches the results of it's optimization.

Comment: This makes little sense, VS2012 doesn't link.  The linker is an entirely different program.  You've got a sick machine.  You need a doctor, not a programmer.

Comment: @HansPassant these problems do not manifest when executing the build process from the command line. So I think it is a VS problem. Also the problems manifest on all Windows machines, not only mine.

Comment: Hmm, if "restarting VS fails" then you certainly have a sick machine problem.  You'll need help from Microsoft support if you are convinced this is a VS problem.